# PhoneGap-Android: Push Notification by Urban Airship from my server

Tags: php, android, cordova, urbanairship.com

I am working in a `Android PhoneGap` app where i need to use `push notification by Urban Airship`. I integrated(`Development+Debug`) Urban Airship push notification in my app and send test push from Urban Airship website and receive push to all device successfully.

But i need to send push notification from my `windows(IIS installed) server(push text and sent time will vary upon server time)`. I want to send push text according to my `schedule task`. Schedule task is complete by PHP code.

So,any clue or idea how can i send push notification from my sever with appropriate schedule?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to change your app from Development to Production stage where it is possible to send push notification from live server.

Comment: see http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/phonegap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can run PHP on your server, following this documentation should get you there - [Urban Airship Simple PHP](https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/91072-simple-php-api-v3-examples)  I have used it and it works great!

You would need to enclose most of it in a function which would then get called by your appropriate schedule.

Edit: added code

```
<?php
 define('APPKEY','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'); // Your App Key
 define('PUSHSECRET', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'); // Your Master Secret
 define('PUSHURL', 'https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/');

 $contents = array();
 $contents['badge'] = "+1";
 $contents['alert'] = "PHP script test";
 $contents['sound'] = "cat.caf";
 $notification = array();
 $notification['ios'] = $contents;
 $platform = array();
 array_push($platform, "ios");

 $push = array("audience"=>"all", "notification"=>$notification, "device_types"=>$platform);

 $json = json_encode($push);
 echo "Payload: " . $json . "\n"; //show the payload

 $session = curl_init(PUSHURL);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, APPKEY . ':' . PUSHSECRET);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, True);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, False);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json', 'Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;'));
 $content = curl_exec($session);
 echo "Response: " . $content . "\n";

 // Check if any error occured
 $response = curl_getinfo($session);
 if($response['http_code'] != 202) {
     echo "Got negative response from server: " . $response['http_code'] . "\n";
 } else {

     echo "Wow, it worked!\n";
 }

 curl_close($session);
?>
```